# Prepopulation of fields from Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app

I have a VF page on Opportunity, when a link is clicked on the page it prompts to create new contact using URL hack- /003/e?accid=.....

This is not working in Salesforce1 properly- ie not pre-populating  fields. Can someone give an example to make this work?

Thanks
laxmi

Comment: URL hacks don't work in Salesforce1. Your options are to use an action or, if you need to do more than an action can handle, create a Visualforce page.

Comment: I did creat a  VF page with standard controller Contact and it goes to - sforce.one.navigateToURL("/003/e?accid=001XXXXXXX");. I am calling this page from my existing page on Opportunity. Still not prepopulating Account name. Is there anythign else that I need to do. Please explain in detail- possibly with example. Many Thanks.

Comment: Jagular- Do you have an example to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO, this is not possible in Salesforce1 using the URL technique that you are trying. [Bob Buzzard](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/416/bob-buzzard) wrote a detailed [blog post](http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.in/2014/01/visualforce-in-salesforce1.html) on this and I believe you may have already seen that (there's a comment as recent as yesterday asking a similar question).

The good thing though is that this is possible with the new Lightning framework using Component Attributes. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_attributes.htm).

Comment: Thanks Gaurav. Is there no other way except using ligtning components? I am asking because somewhere reading posts on internet I get an idea that we can do it via VF page overriding. But not sure how it is applicable in my case. Any thoughts?